# Adding facebook jar to xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin

How can I add this 
https://github.com/facebook/device-year-class
jar to Xamarin project. Because if I add it as a lib to project it's classes cannot be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [binding library guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/). Works well